# Expectation and variance of a stochastic time process conditioned on its past

Tags: probability, variance, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

$$dV_t=-k(V_t-1)dt+ \epsilon\sqrt{V_t}dW_t$$
$W_t$ is wiener process and the rest is just some parameters.

For $T_{i+1}>T_{i}$ how do I find the expectation and variance of $V_{T_{i+1}}$ ***conitional*** to $V_{T_i}$?

Comment: This is a part of a Monte Carlo simulation scheme for a socalled Heston model. I need a distribution for this process to proceed.